# How to download from s3 bucket with ARN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was give this info:

AWS s3 Bucket
ci****a.open

Amazon Resource Name (ARN)
arn:aws:s3:::ci****a.open

AWS Region
US West (Oregon) us-west-2

how am I supposed to download the folder without Access Key ID and Secret Access Key ?
I tried with CLI and it still ask me Access Key ID and Secret Access Key.
I usually use s3 browser, but it also ask for Access Key ID and Secret Access Key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried with CLI and it still ask me Access Key ID and Secret Access Key.

For CLI you have to use [--no-sign-request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/) for credentials to be skipped. This will only work if the objects and/or your bucket is public.

CLI S3 commands, such as [cp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) require [S3Url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-bucket-intro.html#accessing-a-bucket-using-S3-format), not S3 arn:

```
s3://bucket-name
```

you can create it yourself from arn, as bucket-name will be in the arn. In your case it would be `ci****a.open`:

```
s3://ci****a.open
```

So you can try the following to copy everything to current working folder:

```
aws s3 cp s3://ci****a.open . --recursive --no-sign-request
```

Comment: accepted! Wanted to give upvote but I can't since this is my new account

Comment: @NimasAnggarini Thanks. Everyone had to start with new account at one point:-)